# Is it possible to return an AJAX response if the request was not made via AJAX?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a need to present an application error (actually a Symfony2 Exception) modally / as an overlay on the current page if a video asset does not exist. Is it possible to return an Exception from PHP as an Ajax response so that I can inject the error into the originating page without a redirect / browser refresh?

The error message itself will be locale aware and coming from a translation file on the server.

The request comes from javascript like this:

```
    function playVideo(id){
        $(location).attr("href", "{{ app.request.getBaseURL() }}/whatever/player/"+id);
    }
```

Comment: Why not have an ajax call to check if video exits on startup?

Comment: It technically naturally is because - like HTML - the AJAX response is based on text as well and you can return text from PHP very well. However as you have not shown how you structured the application (and more important how the request that triggers the exception is send) it is hard to give concrete suggestions how this could be done. Also I had the same idea as subirkumarsao, provide one AJAX endpoint to get the status of the video, display in case the status is the error condition.

Comment: @hakre thanks I have included the request. I am integrating other people's code so may not have control over how the request is made.

Comment: Do how @subirkumarsao suggested. That should be most straight forward. The playVideo function then probably already know if the video exists or not.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the only other way to do it would be to have the JS always listening for AJAX responses and have routine which decides what to do based on their content